GridDB error cannot build on ubuntu 22.04
I'm getting the following error

3rd_party/MessagePack/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file
'$(srcdir)/src/unpack.c' is in a subdirectory,
3rd_party/MessagePack/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is
disabled

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

add ([subdir-objects])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])

after modify file "configure.ac ", bootstrap.sh can run success.
./configure
mak

got errors like this
./util/code.h: In static member function ‘static void util::ObjectCoder::Impl::decodeInternal(C&, S&, T&, const Attribute&, const Traits&, const util::ObjectCoder::Impl::TypeTagutil::ObjectCoder::TYPE_LIST&)’:
./util/code.h:4771:57: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
4771 | value.push_back(coder.create());
| ^
./util/code.h:4771:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
4771 | value.push_back(coder.create());
| ^
./util/code.h: In static member function ‘static void util::ObjectCoder::Impl::decodeInternal(C&, S&, T&, const Attribute&, const Traits&, const util::ObjectCoder::Impl::TypeTagutil::ObjectCoder::TYPE_OPTIONAL_OBJECT&)’:
./util/code.h:4824:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
4824 | value = coder.create();
| ^
./util/code.h:4824:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
4824 | value = coder.create();

the gcc version here
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 

